# Adding a key value pair in hash, by assigning an array in the value => Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, error-handling, scripting

I'm trying to assign an array in a hash key-value pair as a value of a key. After assigning it i'm trying to dereference it and print the array values from the specific key in an output file as you can see from the code below.

The code is not working well on the array manipulation part. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# File input
my $in_file = 'log.txt';

# Output file
my $out_file_name = 'output.csv';

open(my $fout, '>', $out_file_name);
# print header csv
print $fout "Col1\,Col2\,Col3\,Col4\,Col5\n";

# Read the input file
open(FH, '<', $in_file) or die "Could not open file '$in_file' $!";
my @log_file = <FH>;
# print Dumper(@log_file),"\n";
close (FH);

# my @test_val;

my ($read, $ref, $val_county, $val_rec, $val_tar, $val_print, @test_values, $status);

foreach(@log_file) {
    # print $_;
    if ($_ =~ /\t+(?<county_name>(?!Total).+)\s+/i) {           
        $ref->{code} = $+{county_name};
        $val_county = $ref->{code};
    } elsif ($_ =~ /^Total\s+records\s+in\s+TAR\s+\(pr.+\)\:\s+(?<tar_records>.+)$/i) {
        $ref->{code} = $val_county;
        push(@test_values, $+{tar_records});
        $ref->{tar_rec} = \@test_values;
        # $val_rec = $ref->{tar_rec};
        # $val_rec =~ s/\.//g;
    }

    &print_file($ref);

}


sub print_file {
    my $ref = shift;    
    my $status = shift; 
    print $fout join(",", $ref->{code}, [@{$ref->{tar_rec}}]), "\n";  # Line 68
    print Dumper($ref);
}

close $fout;

print "Done!","\n";
```

The code is a providing an error like:
"Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at test_array_val_hash.pl line 68."

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call subroutines with an & before them any more - that's very old school perl.

Comment: Also...your code doesn't have 68 lines so that error message is meaningless

Comment: The error is from the print_file subroutine, and is refering to the next line:
print $fout join(",", $ref->{code}, [@{$ref->{tar_rec}}]), "\n";

Sorry for the created confusion. I took out only the code that was referring to the steps that intend to follow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `print_file` in the wrong place.

Imagine that you're parsing the file a line at a time. Your code parses the first line and that populates `$ref->{code}`. But then you call `print_file` on a partially populated `$ref` so it doesn't work.

Your code is also not resetting any of the variables used, so as it progresses through the file, the contents of `$ref` are going to grow.

The code below fixes the first problem by implicitly setting an empty array in `$ref->{tar_rec}` and only printing out the record when it's starting a new one or when it's finished reading in the file. Since `$ref->{tar_rec}` is an array it solves the other problem by allowing you to directly push into it rather than relying upon `@test_values`. Just for added safety it assigns an empty hash to `$ref`.

```
if(open(my $fh, '<', $in_file)) {
    my $ref;
    my $val_county;

    foreach(<$fh>) {
        # print $_;
        if ($_ =~ /\t+(?<county_name>(?!Total).+)\s+/i) {
            if(defined($val_county)) {
                print_file($ref);
            }

            $ref={};
            $val_county = $+{county_name};
            $ref->{code} = $val_county;
            $ref->{tar_rec} = [];
        } elsif ($_ =~ /^Total\s+records\s+in\s+TAR\s+\(pr.+\)\:\s+(?<tar_records>.+)$
            push @{$ref->{tar_rec}}, $+{tar_records};
        }
    }
    if(defined($ref)) {
        print_file($ref);
    }
    close($fh);

} else {
    die "Could not open file '$in_file' $!";
}
```

You're also printing out the array incorrectly

```
print $fout join(",", $ref->{code}, [@{$ref->{tar_rec}}]), "\n";
```

you don't need any brackets around `@{$ref->{tar_rec}}` - it'll be treated as a list of values to pass to `join` as is.

```
print $fout join(",", $ref->{code}, @{$ref->{tar_rec}}), "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks to all for help. Chris, your solution is doing the right thing now. Thanks for helping and for your time. 
It seems that Perl does me to many tricks !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Until the second regex in your forloop block is matched, the `$ref->{tar_rec}` key will not be assigned a value - and will be undefined. The following snippet - based on your own code - highlights the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @tar_records = (15,35,20);

my $ref = {
    code => 'Cork',
    tar_rec => \@tar_records,
};

sub print_info {
    my $ref = shift;
    print join(", ", $ref->{code}, (@{$ref->{tar_rec}})), $/;
}

print_info($ref);

# Once we 'undefine' the relevant key, we witness the afore-
#  mentioned error.
undef $ref->{tar_rec};

print_info($ref);
```

To avoid this error, you could assign an anonymous array reference to `$ref->{tar_rec}` key *before* the for loop (since `$ref->{tar_rec}` is a cumulative value).

```
# Be sure not to declare $ref twice!
my ($read, $val_county, $val_rec, $val_tar, $val_print, @test_values, $status);
my $ref = {
    code => '',
    tar_rec => [],
}
```

P.S. Notice also that I used round brackets rather than square brackets in the `join()` function (although you actually don't need either).